# Why do I see a MSVCR90 dependency even though I set the /MT option?

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

I'm building a DLL in Visual C++ 2008, and I want to have the runtime statically linked into the DLL.  So I went into the project options and set Runtime Library to `Multi-threaded (/MT)`.  This has always worked for other projects in the past.  But when I build this one, I still end up with Dependency Walker showing MSVCR90.dll in the list.

Anyone know what could cause that?

Comment: Clearly the EXE that loads your DLL was not built with the same option.  Or another DLL that got loaded, it takes only one.

Comment: @Hank: Not applicable here.  I'm looking at it in Dependency Walker, and it shows at the top level of the tree, not under another loaded DLL.

Comment: What export(s) in `MSVCR90` is your DLL dependent on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project + Properties, Linker, Command Line.  Add the /verbose option.  Build + Rebuild.  The Output window shows you the linker searching for symbols.  Watch out for msvcrt.lib, that's the one that pulls in the dependency on msvcr90.dll

The typical cause is linking a .lib that has one or more .obj files that were compiled with /MD.  A dependency on msvcrt.lib gets injected with the #pragma comment(lib, msvcrt.lib) directive.  That tells the linker to search msvcrt.lib without you explicitly specifying it as a dependency in Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be exactly what it was.